# Cannot cut part of note, instead removing whole notes

Tags: reason

In Reason 11

...I have used the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> and made a cut with it.

I used the selection tool <kbd>Q</kbd> to select the part to the left of the cut.

I delete the selection with <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Notes that starts in the left part, but ends in the right part will be deleted, not truncated.

Why?

## 1

[image: Before delete]

## 2

<kbd>Delete</kbd>

## 3

[image: After delete]

## edit

Zoomed in, showing starting points

[image: zoomed in]

Comment: I don't use Reason, but I expect those first two notes actually start JUST before the vertical white line. Can you examine their starting-points?

Comment: I added that as an edit.

Comment: I also don’t use Reason but can you use the knife tool in the piano roll editor to cut the individual notes instead? If not then maybe move the start time of the notes to where the cut is?

Comment: If you want them to be truncated then shorten them before making the cut. If you DON'T want that and you want them to sound as they do at the moment, do you have to make the cut?

Comment: The cut itself should truncate them? How is the actual behavior the expected one?

Comment: I suggest you read the manual, or ask people who actually USE Reason.

Comment: I expect a lot of users in this forum to be Reason users.